# How to change the h1 tag inside a div with the help of map function in react functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-functional-component

```
const fruit = ["Apple", "Mango", "Litchi", "Pineapple"]


<div class="container">
    <div class="left-container">
        <h1>{fruit}</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried to map the value of fruit for every h1 tag but it is not doing the mapping

Comment: You will need to use a `map` to loop thru your array and render it

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this ? Or please write more details how you want your final result result.

```
const fruit = ["Apple", "Mango", "Litchi", "Pineapple"]


<div class="container">
    <div class="left-container">
        { fruit.map(f => <h1>{f}</h1> ) }
    </div>
</div>
```